# Scrolling with ScrollViewer causes App crash

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

In Windows 10 Universal app development the ScrollViewer causes App crashes. In the Windows dev Center this was also mentioned but not solved (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/a737f407-d59f-4b10-a7d0-de9ead6d4f5f/uwpscrollviewer-occasional-crash?forum=wpdevelop).
Now my Problem:

I put a second grid on the Standard one of the xaml file. Then I added the ScrollViewer to this grid. After that i put another grid on the scrollviewer and then i added some Buttons to this grid. When scrolling the app crashes very often.

[image]

Do you have any idea how to fix that or how it can be done different?

Here the Code:

```
<Page
x:Class="ProjectMoralsKite.Datenbank"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ProjectMoralsKite"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid x:Name="grid">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="529" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="340" BorderThickness="0,-1,0,0" Background="White" Opacity="0.6"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,70,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Verwaltung" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="340" FontSize="29.333"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Zurück" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,507,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Click="button_Click"/>

    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="380" Margin="10,109,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="340">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="655" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="340">
            <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Plan" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="54" Width="340"/>
            <Button x:Name="button1_Copy" Content="Kunden" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,83,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="54" Width="340" Click="button1_Copy_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="button1_Copy1" Content="Baustellen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,142,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="54" Width="340" Click="button1_Copy1_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="button1_Copy2" Content="Aufträge" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,201,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="54" Width="340" Background="#33000000" Click="button1_Copy2_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="button1_Copy3" Content="Zuweisung" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,260,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="54" Width="340" Background="#33FF0000"/>
            <Button x:Name="button1_Copy4" Content="Rechteverwaltung" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,319,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="54" Width="340" Background="#33FF0000"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: It would probably be easier for us to help you, if you show your code.

Comment: I can't reproduce, the code is not crashing. However it's still bad written since is uses fixed-dimension elements and layouts

Comment: I use Visual Blend to port the app to different Screen resolutions. So why it should be a bad idea to use fixed-dimension Elements? How would you do it different?